# HTML code to render image useless

Tags: html

I am using an IFTTT integration:

> If new RSS feed item, then send myself a Gmail email

I use `{{EntryContent}}` inside the body of the email.

In my specific case, `{{EntryContent}}` contains `<img>` elements, among other, which I want to render useless, i.e. make them not show up in my email body.

Example `{{EntryContent}}`:

```html
<p><a href="https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg"><img data-attachment-id="899263" data-permalink="https://stadt-bremerhaven.de/pokemon-go-ei-spektakel-bringt-besondere-pokemon-doppelten-sternenstaub-und-mehr/pogo_eggstravaganza/" data-orig-file="https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg?fit=1024%2C512&amp;ssl=1" data-orig-size="1024,512" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="pogo_eggstravaganza" data-image-description="" data-medium-file="https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg?fit=720%2C360&amp;ssl=1" data-large-file="https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg?fit=720%2C360&amp;ssl=1" src="https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg?resize=720%2C360" alt="" width="720" height="360" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-899263" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg?resize=720%2C360&amp;ssl=1 720w, https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg?resize=768%2C384&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i0.wp.com/stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pogo_eggstravaganza.jpg?w=1024&amp;ssl=1 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 720px) 100vw, 720px" data-recalc-dims="1" /></a><br /> Gute Nachrichten für alle Pokémon GO-Trainer! Am 22. März startet um 21 Uhr das <a href="https://pokemongolive.com/post/eggstravaganza2018/">diesjährige Ei-Spektakel</a>. Das bringt gleich mehrere
```

Using HTML elements only, is there any way to render this content useless so that images don't show and only plain text is displayed?

I already tried `<textarea>{{EntryContent}}</textarea>` but it was only applied to the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have access to a `<style>` tag if you are able to wrap the content in a text area. In the body of the email you could put a style tag:

```
<style>
  img[data-permalink] { display: none; }
</style>
```

Add any other things you want to hide as well.

Comment: Great idea! Unfortunately style is not allowed by IFTTT to be used in the body. Screencast: https://youtu.be/PuaR2O1k_6U

Comment: Also tried code tags but it only renders the text to code leaving the image as is: https://youtu.be/zoIPMvCJRRs

Comment: Are you required to use IFTTT? I believe there's some other free options that let you have more customization. I *think* this one does it but you would have to check: https://www.feedio.co/ -- theres more listed here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-free-RSS-to-email-service

Comment: No, doesn't have to be IFTTT. Checked feedio but cannot see how I can achieve what I need.